# Two sites one PC

Tags: plugins, php, themes, permissions

after [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920420/wordpress-strange-permission-issue) I think that there is a problem if I have two wordpress installation on one pc. I've fallow [this instruction](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-a-single-ubuntu-vps) and the only thing is that I've change the wp-contents folder like this

```
* Default value for some constants if they have not yet been set
   by the host-specific config files */
if (!defined('ABSPATH'))
    define('ABSPATH', '/var/www/aniabuchi/');
if (!defined('WP_CORE_UPDATE'))
    define('WP_CORE_UPDATE', false);
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
if (!defined('WP_CONTENT_DIR') && !defined('DONT_SET_WP_CONTENT_DIR'))
    define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/var/www/aniabuchi/wp-content');
```

So the problem is that nothing I've install into the second wordpress is working correct or visible. I've upload Media, Install themes and plugins but I can't see their resources such as images and etc. 
I think that this is Alias problem - I have the same alias into every site.conf under /etc/apache2/site-available 

 first_site.conf -> Alias /wp-content /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content

 second_site.conf -> Alias /wp-content /var/www/aniabuchi/wp-content
 
 but how can I resolve it

Comment: You point to the digitalocean toturial, but your code has nothing to do with it? what is that code supposed to do at all?

Comment: this was the default file I just change the text inside ...

Comment: default of what/ this is not something normal wordpress has

Comment: Assuming you have created a symbolic link for each virtual host and restarted Apache makes it a: almost impossible for us to help (can be multiple reasons, steps missing important things) b: has absolutely nothing to do with WordPress, Did you check each site fist with just an index.html to see if they show any at all (no need to have any cms installed at all for that). To me It seems a Server (setup/configuration) issue and is therefore imho off-topic, sorry.

Comment: the both websites are working, I can access both admin panels using /wp-admin/ but any media,pictures and resource from the second one isn't visible. They both have the same user owner and the same user permissions.

Comment: I wanna know how I can make one wordpress to work with site.com/wp-content... and the other wordpress install to work with secondsite.com/content/....

Comment: You will have to edit your question and add your conf files. Without anymore info and no case to reproduce it looks impossible.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are doing everything wrong. You should just use 1 WP installation and **ENABLE MULTI-SITE feature**, and then you can open as many separate WP sites as you want!

## **NO NEED TO INSTALL separate WORDPRESS installations.**

Answer (score -3):

So I was right and the problem was the alias so no one tell me how to resolve it. I thinking about how can I rename the wp-content for the second wordpress installation. I found a simple tutorial [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/renaming-wordpress-wp-content-folder/) and after made everything from tutorial with the rename procedure now all resources are available.

Comment: So I was correct by stating that it is/was a Server issue but it's great to hear you solved it.